# Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]

Tags: c, int

```
// set all values in the hash table to null
for(int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
{
    hashtable[i] = NULL;
}
```

I keep getting this error message in response to hashtable[i]:

> assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `hashtable` is an array of integers then `hashtable[i]` expects an integer and `NULL` is a pointer.

So you're trying to assign a pointer value to an integer variable(without a cast), this is usually just a warning but since you have `-Werror` all warnings turn into errors.

Just use `0` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I could also declare an array of pointers and store the value that way.  I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

NULL is defined as `(void*)0` in `stddef.h`

```
#ifndef _LINUX_STDDEF_H
#define _LINUX_STDDEF_H

#undef NULL
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define NULL 0
#else
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#endif

#endif
```

If the hashtable is integer array, like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HASH_SIZE 100
int main()
{
int i = 0, hashtable[HASH_SIZE];
for(i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
{
    hashtable[i] = NULL;
}
return 0;
}
```

this `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`         will be shown.

Comment: What makes you believe the OP uses Linux? What makes you believe NULL must be defined in this particular way? Note that making assumptions by extrapolation from one system makes you in for surprises. Instead, reading and citing the ISO C Standard is likely to provide definitive answers. Such answers are independent of OS and header contents.

Comment: @Jens, Thanks. I will try to follow ISO C std :)